# UCase Previously Active Cell

Tags: excel, vba

In column G, I always want whatever I've typed into it to be converted to uppercase

This code works except it does the cell I've newly selected, and not the one I just modified, which is what I need.

So instead of this modifying the active cell, I want it to modify the previously active cell. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveCell.Column = 7 Then ActiveCell = UCase(ActiveCell)
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Worksheet_SelectionChange` to `Worksheet_Change` and all `ActiveCell` to `Target`

Comment: And don't forget to toggle events on and off using `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `... = True`, to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: This worked quite well. Thanks.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Column = 7 Then Target = UCase(Target)
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub